# There is no enhancement tab for sound of my windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio

My laptop with Windows 10 pre-installed has a relatively low volume, and I just found out that there is no enhancement tab when I went to the properties of the sound.

Could anyone please tell me what should I do? The laptop is MSI-ge62 6qd, the sound driver from Realtek is installed.

Comment: Left click the speaker icon in the system tray to increase volume.

Comment: [This answer](http://superuser.com/a/1015738/135137) helped me.

Comment: @Moab Hi thanks for your answer! Actually I know how to increase volume, what I mean is that the volume is relatively even when the volume is increased to 100.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune Actually as I mentioned in the question, there is no audio manager tray nor enhancement tab.